# Using golang's mgo library, how do you retrieve nested objects such as lists

Tags: go, mgo

I am trying to retrieve an object that fills this class:

```
type Room struct {
    Name   string
    People []Person
    Chat   []ChatMessage
    Me     Person
}
```

The data field "People" comes up as an empty slice [].  I am using a simple find to get the data.

```
result := Room{}
err = c.Find(bson.M{"name": "dev"}).One(&result)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Figured it out....

The answer can be found here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mgo-users/KirqfCSlKFc/t2l3l4yxFRwJ

Basically, just need to add 'bson: ""' at the end of the People []Person line

Comment: Did you check if there are actually people stored?

Comment: Rather than just editing your question, consider creating an answer for your question for the benefit of others.

Comment: It didn't let me at the time.  I'm a bit new to posting on this site.

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out....

The answer can be found here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mgo-users/KirqfCSlKFc/t2l3l4yxFRwJ

Basically, just need to add 'bson: ""' at the end of the People []Person line